# Get pixel color from IMG is always 0 0 0 0?

Tags: javascript, canvas, google-maps-api-3

In my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jw42w43o/), I have a marker that I can move around and update Lat Long values in textboxes respectively. When I move the marker I update an IMG with a smaller scale of what is under the marker and display it right under the Google Map. I can do all of this successfully.

However, what I want to do now is get Pixel data in position (0,0) loaded in IMG so that I can get a sense of the color of the pixels under the marker, but no matter what I do I always get 0 0 0 0!

I know the IMG is loading correctly as you can see a small box under my major Google Map. But I feel there is something wrong in the following:

```
    var canvas = $('<canvas/>')[0];
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);             
    var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
```

However, I have seen multiple solutions that use very similar fragment of code to achieve what I want.

Any help is very much appreciated!

**CSS:**

```
#map 
{
   width: 525px;
   height: 500px;
}

img#mapImg 
{
   display: block;
}
```

**Body:**

```
<div  id="map"></div>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
<br /><br /><br />
<label for="xGps">Lat:</label>
<input id="xGps" type="number" value="32.765813" />
<label for="yGps">Long:</label>
<input id="yGps" type="number" value="-79.875535" />

<img id="mapImg" src="" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
 function getColor() {
    var img = document.getElementById('mapImg');

    img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';

    var xGps = $("#xGps").val();
    var yGps = $("#yGps").val();

    var mapUrl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" 
                 + xGps + "," + yGps 
                 + "&zoom=14&size=50x50&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false";

    $(img).attr("src", mapUrl);

    var canvas = $('<canvas/>')[0];
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);             
    var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;

    $("#result").html(pixelData[0] + " " + pixelData[1] + " " 
                    + pixelData[2] + " " + pixelData[3]);
 }

 function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      'zoom': 12,
      'center': new google.maps.LatLng(32.765813, -79.914237),
      'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    });

    marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: map,
       position: new google.maps.LatLng(32.753512, -79.875535),
       draggable: true,
       raiseOnDrag: true
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'drag', function (event) {
       document.getElementById('xGps').value = event.latLng.lat();
       document.getElementById('yGps').value = event.latLng.lng();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'dragend', function (event) {
       document.getElementById('xGps').value = event.latLng.lat();
       document.getElementById('yGps').value = event.latLng.lng();
       getColor();
    });
}
```

**Updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jw42w43o/2/) with solution. Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wait the image load.

try:

```
 $(img).attr("src", mapUrl).load(function(){

    var canvas = $('<canvas/>')[0];
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);             
    var pixelData = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;

    $("#result").html(pixelData[0] + " " + pixelData[1] + " " 
                    + pixelData[2] + " " + pixelData[3]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks @hexa heart, exactly what I needed!